# Marquee string (scroll the text left)

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I would like to have a generic function that scrolls left the text.
Given that, I have made this:

```
void marquee2(std::string& text) {
    std::string temp = text;
    text.erase(0, 1);
    text += temp[0];
}
```

It works like a charm.

If you call it like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::string test = "Now playing - TEST.MP3 - ";
    while (true)
    {
        marquee2(test);
        SetConsoleTitleA(test.c_str());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me the desired result:

```
Now playing - TEST.MP3 - 
ow playing - TEST.MP3 - N
w playing - TEST.MP3 - No
 playing - TEST.MP3 - Now
playing - TEST.MP3 - Now 
laying - TEST.MP3 - Now p
aying - TEST.MP3 - Now pl
ying - TEST.MP3 - Now pla
ing - TEST.MP3 - Now play
ng - TEST.MP3 - Now playi
g - TEST.MP3 - Now playin
 - TEST.MP3 - Now playing
- TEST.MP3 - Now playing 
 TEST.MP3 - Now playing -
TEST.MP3 - Now playing -
```

and so on...

But the main problem is, when I want to limit the string.
So, I Would like my function to be altered in a way so it should limit the result string.

`void marquee_limit(std::string& msg, size_t limit)`

Given "TEST" and 2, the desired result:

```
TE
ES
ST
TT
TE
ES
ST
TT
```

and so on...  Given TEST and 3:

```
TES
EST
STT
TTE
TES
EST
STT
TTE
```

and so on...  Given "NOW PLAYING - " and 3:

```
NOW
OW 
W P
 PL
PLA
LAY
AYI
YIN
ING
NG 
G -
 - 
- N
 NO
NOW
```

and repeat the sequence...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to modify your existing function like this:

```
std::string marquee_limit(std::string& text, size_t limit) {
    std::string temp = text;
    text.erase(0, 1);
    text += temp[0];

    return text.substr(0,limit);
}
```

and then call it like this in your while-loop:

```
while (true)
{
    SetConsoleTitleA(marquee_limit(test,2).c_str());
}
```

Comment: It doesn't do what i need. Given "NOW PLAYING - ", I got `NOW` `OWN` `WNO` `NOW` `OWN` `WNO` and so on, not the full string. :(

Comment: increase the `limit`. It's currently set to 2: `(marquee2(test,2)`

Comment: Also take a look at the concept of a circular buffer.

Comment: Here is the result I get: http://pastebin.com/3hHPn3K9 To me that looks like what you want. Are you sure you are using the function the right way?